# Accessing Apache Kafka deployed on OpenShift through route

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift

I've set up Apache Kafka on OpenShift using this helm repository by bitnami:
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/kafka

I am using the latest version of the helm chart (20.0.1)

When I try to connect to it externally I get this error

```
ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I am looking to deploy Apache Kafka using Bitnami's helm chart

I've tried changing inside values.yaml:
`externalAccess.enabled: true`
`externalAccess.service.type=ClusterIP`
`externalAccess.service.ports.external: 80`
`externalAccess.service.domain: my-route-host`

I've created a route object:

```
spec:
  host: my-route-host
  port:
    targetPort: tcp-kafka
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: kafka-helm-0-external
```

the external service:

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: tcp-kafka
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: kafka-external
```

the pod's ports:

```
ports:
  - name: kafka-client
    containerPort: 9092
    protocol: TCP
  - name: kafka-internal
    containerPort: 9093
    protocol: TCP
  - name: kafka-external
    containerPort: 9094
    protocol: TCP
```

Inside the pod's server.properties:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://:9093,CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9094
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://my-pod-host:9093,CLIENT://my-pod-host:9092,EXTERNAL://my-route-host:80
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use Bitnami charts and trying to manually integrate that into OpenShift, you can use [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/30/accessing-kafka-part-3/) instead, which already offers Route support.

Snippet

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    # ...
    listeners:
      # ...
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: route
        tls: true
```

Also, your error is unrelated to if you have a Route, or not. You need to increase the heap space of your consumer process.

Comment: Hi, that error occurs when there is no access to the kafka cluster and isn't actually related to memory heap space.
I've also specified that I need to use bitnami's chart.

Comment: Okay, well, bitnami doesn't support OpenShift last I checked. You'll need to separately deploy HAProxy, like Strimzi does, or Nginx, then configure Kafka behind those since Routes **only** support HTTP traffic, not Kafka TCP.... For your heap errors, give it more heap with `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`  variable, but also it's throwing errors because the connection protocol is wrong